# How to prevent resource loading by using userscript?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I am trying to write a userscript which can replace the content of a website with custom content. But when loading the website, my browser still download the js and css files which aren't used. And the original content still shows for a while. Are there any better solution to prevent these resources loading?

This is my code:

PS: The event `beforescriptexecute` can only be used in Firefox, I found that in MDN.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        New script - example.com
// @match       https://example.com/
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

const obs = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    for (let mut of mutationsList) {
      for (let node of mut.addedNodes) {
        if (node.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
          node.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', (e) => { // Bad
            e.preventDefault();
          });
          node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
        }
      }
    }
});

obs.observe(document.documentElement, { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  obs.disconnect();
  document.head.innerHTML = '';
  document.body.innerHTML = `<p>Hello World</p>`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        New script - example.com
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://example.com/
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==
 
const obs = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
  for (const mut of mutationsList) {
    for (const node of mut.addedNodes) {
      if (node.tagName === 'SCRIPT' || node.tagName === 'STYLE') {
        // console.log(node);
        node.remove();
      }
    }
  }
});

obs.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });

function clearHeadAndBody() {
  document.head.innerHTML = '';
  document.body.innerHTML = `<p>Hello World</p>`;
  setTimeout(() => {
    obs.disconnect();
  }, 1000);
}

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  /**
   * Sometimes, the page is done loading before the script is
   * injected, usually when reloading the page. In this case
   * we run the code from here.
   */
  clearHeadAndBody();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', clearHeadAndBody);
}
```